# firebase dynamic link error on IOS "Deep Link does not contain valid required params"

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links, applinks

My app is an ionic app and i use cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks it works on android 
   but on ios i get this error:

```
6.19.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    "_cpb" = 1;
    "_cpt" = cpit;
    "_fpb" = "CJsFEPcCGgJlbg==";
    "_iumchkactval" = 0;
    "_iumenbl" = 1;
    "_osl" = "https://khanoo.page.link/test2";
    "_plt" = 1260;
    "_uit" = 2887;
    apn = "com.codex.khanoo";
    cid = 7661467918835935158;
    ibi = "codex.khanoo";
    isi = 1446149404;
    link = "https://khanoo.com/tabs/estates/id/6155?page=estate&pageId=198";
    sd = "very nice";
    si = "https://khanoo.com/backend/thumbnails/estates/5e6a9552807f4/0-5e6a95528082e.jpeg";
    st = house;
}
```

my Bundle ID is `codex.khanoo`  and i added it to info url type url schemes i also added `GoogleService-info.plist`

and also in firebase console i added everything `Bundle ID` , `App Store ID`
and `Team ID`

Comment: I'm not an ionic developer but an ios dev. does the ionic generates an iOS project, because if it does, you will need to add that url scheme in the info.plist file.

Comment: Yes it will generate IOS project and i added my bundle id to url scheme in info.plist file which is codex.khanoo

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem myself before, been looking for solution for days, turns out my link is not properly encoded, so make sure this link is encoded properly

```
link = "https://khanoo.com/tabs/estates/id/6155?page=estate&pageId=198";
```

In PHP you can use `urlencode(YOUR_LINK)` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

In Ruby you can use `ERB::Util.url_encode(YOUR_LINK)`

Comment: I am getting this error too and tried the url encoding but its not working.  Using javascript I encoded the link with both encodeURI and encodeURIComponent - but neither fixed the issue.  The deep link does open my app, but the window.handleOpenUrl global function never fires to capture the passed in parameters.

Comment: i then tried a very basic url: `var test = "action?a=12345&b=67890&c=HelloYou" ;  test = encodeURIComponent(test) ;` then called `myapp://+test` - and in the iOS app it then said `Deep Link Web URL query is empty`

Comment: @rolinger Any solution found?

Comment: My issue turned out to be the latest version of the twitter plugin `cordova-plugin-twitter-connect-webview` was intereferring with customurlscheme's plugin when calling `wndow.handleOpenURL()` - I removed the plugin for now and my app is working again.  I have also found/read that other cordova plugins like `facebook` also caused this same issue.